# Safe way to get a string representation of any JavaScript value or object

Tags: javascript

I want to get a string represention of any object or value in JavaScript. I did a couple of experiments.

```
> var a = document.createTextNode('foo'); a
  "foo"
> var a = document.createTextNode('foo'); a.toString()
  "[object Text]"
> var a = 1; a.toString()
  "1"
> (1).toString()
  "1"
> 1.toString()
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

I have the following questions:

1. Why does `1.toString()` fail?
2. Will the following function return me a string representation of every possible JavaScript object, value or literal? Function: `function str(a) {return a.toString()}`
3. Is there any other alternative to the `function str` I have written in the previous point?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25564831/difference-between-numbers-using-or-without-using-variable/25564863#25564863

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24902061/is-there-an-repr-equivalent-for-javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1). Why does `1.toString()` fail?

The JavaScript parser only uses a 1 character lookahead and can't determine if that's `1.0` or `1.toString()`. You can use `1..toString()` to get around that.

> 2). Will the following function return me a string representation of every possible JavaScript object, value or literal? Function: `function str(a) {return a.toString()}`

Any literal will be converted to a temporary object in order to have its `toString()` called. If the object has its own `toString()` defined, it will be called. Otherwise, it will use `Object.prototype.toString()` (having gone up the prototype chain) for almost all cases (the other case is an object with a `null` prototype).

> 3). Is there any other alternative to the function `str` I have written in the previous point?

Yes. You can invoke the `toString()` implicitly by concatenating an empty string, e.g. `1 + ""`. You can also use the `String` constructor, e.g. `String(value)` (thanks T.J. Crowder). The advantages of these other ones is no exception will be thrown if you attempt to call `toString()` on `null` or `undefined`.

However, these tricks will convert `null` and `undefined` to their string equivalents (almost never what you want). One dirty trick is to put the value in a literal array, e.g. `[value]` and then call `toString()` on it. This will actually invoke `join(",")`, but seeing as it only has one member, the comma will never become part of the string.

The real power of doing this is that `null` and `undefined` will just become an empty string. If that's OK for your program, then it can be useful. Keep in mind to comment this solution as it's not immediately obvious what this code is doing. Alternatively, check `value == null` which will detect `null` and `undefined` and handle it appropriately.

However, if you're wanting a string in order to classify a value, you can get the type's [`[[Class]]`](http://es5.github.io/#x8.6.2) like so...

```
var getInternalClass = function(value) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(value).slice(8, -1); 
};
```

This will invoke the `Object`'s `toString()` and set the `ThisBinding` to the value provided as the argument. This is the only way to expose an object's internal `[[Class]]`. The advantage of this (over `typeof`, for example) is that primitives and objects will always return the same value (with the primitives being converted to temporary objects, *boxed* by the `call()` context in non-strict mode).

Comment: Or by using the `String` constructor as a converter: `String(1)` returns `"1"`.

Comment: Indeed. It's probably worth pointing out to the OP that either your concatenation or using `String` will avoid throwing an exception where `a.toString()` will throw, if `a` is `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: @alex Would you please elaborate the answer to 1. Why should 1 character lookahead be a problem? JS parser first reads `1`. Then it reads `1.`. It doesn't know if it's `1.0` coming up or `1.toString()` coming up. Now it reads `1.t` and it would know that it is not `1.0` but a function call on `1`. what's the problem here?

Comment: @LoneLearner Been a while since I looked at tokenising stuff so I'm not sure now. However, I found [this comment](https://github.com/BonsaiDen/JavaScript-Garden/issues/84#issuecomment-1452557) which seems to make the same claim. If you can wait for me to look back into it, I can come back and edit the answer (but it will be months). :)

Comment: Which one of these has the best performance? Excluding `.toString()` of course.

Comment: @benjaminz Not sure, but it's probably unlikely to become the bottleneck in a real app.

Answer (score 1):

for `1.toString()`, you need to do:

```
1 .toString() //add space before dot (.) to avoid taking it as decimal
```

shortest way (alternative to `function str` ) to convert to string is:

```
var str = str + '';
```

Comment: Instead of doing `str = str + ''` one can also do `str = String(str)` (Note the missing `new` operator! `String` is also a function!) which is somewhat easier to read / more ideomatic.

Answer (score 0):

Your `str(a)` function is correct but it will call the `default implementation` of `toString()` inherited from `Object`. So yes, your function will give you `string` representation of every JS object but not in way you want it. You need to override it.

```
var o = new Object();
o.toString();           // returns [object Object]
```

See here for reference and overriding: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString

Comment: Could you please elaborate by what you mean by "not in the way you want it"? I want whatever string is returned by the `toString()` function. Why do I have to override `toString()`? Is every object and literal in JavaScript provided with a default implementation of `toString()`? If yes, that's all I need.

Comment: @LoneLearner, if you need the default implementation of every object and literal then this will work. But if you want customized value, then you need to override it.