# difference between numbers using or without using variable

Tags: javascript

What's the difference between the following code?

```
var a = 1;
a.toString(); // outputs: "1"
```

But this throws an error:

```
1.toString();
```

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Why? Why does the first code work but the second code throws an error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With method invocations, it is important to distinguish between the **floating-point dot** and the **method invocation dot**.
Thus, you cannot write `1.toString();` you must use one of the following alternatives:

```
1..toString()
1 .toString() //space before dot
(1).toString()
1.0.toString()
```

Answer (score 1):

> The [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) method returns a string representing object.

So when you call:

```
a.toString();
```

You are actually operating on an object. You are actually creating a built-in object when you define a variable(in this case it is a number).

When you do this:

```
1.toString();
```

toString() doesn't see `1` as an object or a variable(both are the same in this scenario) because it fails the rule:

> Variable must begin with a letter

Here `1` doesn't begin with a letter. So `toString()` knows it is not operating on an object and throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Change the Syntax,

(1).toString()

Numbers can have decimals, so the syntax for ending in a decimal is a bit ambiguous when you go to parse the code, use parenthesis to be valid. It's a bit clearer when you see that this is also valid:

(1.).toString()

However with just

1.toString() it's trying to parse as a number with a decimal, and it fails.