# In Javascript - Why this doesn't fail?

Tags: javascript

```
100..toString() // "100"
100 . toString() // "100"
```

Not able to understand why it doesn't fail? What is happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Space doesn't matter but allow you to separate the floating point number and the method so `100 . toString();` returns output correctly without throwing error. And with `100.toString()`, it would throw an error as JavaScript store the number as floating point number so you need to separate between floating point dot and the invocation dot so `100..toString();` returns correct result.

See [related question for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25564831/difference-between-numbers-using-or-without-using-variable).

Answer (score 0):

The first dot ensures the "100" is parsed as a float.  The second accesses the member.